# Loop over ActiveRecord rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I know I can do

```
@somethings.each do |something|
/*some work with something*/
end
```

but I want to know if I can loop over @somethings with a for

I tried

```
for i in 0..10
    @somethings[i].myattribute
end
```

but it is not giving me the object I want, or any object as far as I know.

I need to use the for loop, I cannot do what I want with "each". So is it possible to use a for loop somehow?

Comment: well, if you must know: I am using Rhomobile to develop my app and I haven't been able to sort the records the way I need, so alternatively I could use the for loop to iterate through records the way I want.

Comment: Works for me, assuming there's a typo in your second example.

Comment: Why exactly can you not do what you need to with `each`? I can't fathom any situation where a `for` loop would be required over an iterator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for something in @somethings
  something.myattribute
end
```

or weird

```
@somethings_array = @somethings.to_a
for i in 0..10
  @somethings_array[i].myattribute
end
```

ok

```
@somethings_array = @somethings.to_a
10.downto(1) do |i|
  @somethings_array[i].myattribute
end
```

Comment: Thank you, but that is not what I am looking for. I need the index

Answer (score 3):

If the collection you're working is enumerable, you can use the each_with_index method, like this:

```
@somethings.each_with_index do |something, i|
  something[i].an_attribute
end
```

This should almost certainly do what you want.